# how to add section number and name to the page header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to modify the page layout of my thesis. I'd like to have at the top-right corner the section number **and section title** and at the top left corner the page number.

Using the following:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thesection}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
```

I get what expected. However I'd like to add the section name. I've tried:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thesection}{thesectiontitle}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
```

but of course it didn't work. I think it requires a bit more of programming but I only have a basic Latex tutorial so far where I can't find useful information. Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Maybe what you want, roughly, is: `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}` and then in `\lhead{\rightmark}`.  But I think you have your description and code reversed.  And is your thesis going to be 'one-sided'?

Comment: @jon Wanna write up an answer and get this off the list of unanswered questions? Thanks.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- No problem.

Answer (score 3):

(Based on an earlier comment.)

Adding this to the preamble

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
```

and then changing `\lhead` in the following way

```
\lhead{\rightmark}
```

seems to have solved this problem.